# Error enlarging buttons on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, button, image-enlarge

Hello im trying to enlarge my buttons on eclipse. I found this code on the web that suppose to fix it
but it keeps giving me the error

`Error: Could not find or load main class testEclipse.FixIcons`

Any idea what can i do?
Im pretty new at this .. thanks

```
package testEclipse;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLine;
import org.apache.commons.cli.GnuParser;
import org.apache.commons.cli.Option;
import org.apache.commons.cli.Options;
import org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.imgscalr.Scalr;

import com.mortennobel.imagescaling.AdvancedResizeOp;
import com.mortennobel.imagescaling.ResampleOp;

/**
 * Small utility to double the size of eclipse icons for QHD monitors.
 * 
 * @author David Levy
 * @since 2014/04/10
 *
 */
public class FixIcons {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FixIcons.class);

public static final void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        Options options = new Options();

        options.addOption(new Option("b", "baseDir", true,
                "This is the base directory where we'll parse jars/zips"));
        options.addOption(new Option("o", "outputDir", true,
                "This is the base directory where we'll place output"));
        for (Option o : new ArrayList<Option>(options.getOptions())) {
            o.setRequired(true);
        }

        GnuParser parser = new GnuParser();
        CommandLine commandLine = parser.parse(options, args);
        String baseDirArg = "D:\\things\\tools\\eclipse";
        logger.info("Base directory: " + baseDirArg);

        String outputDirArg = "D:\\things\\tools\\eclipsetmp";
        logger.info("Output directory: " + outputDirArg);

        File base = new File(baseDirArg);
        if (!base.exists() || !base.canRead() || !base.isDirectory()) {
            logger.error("Unable to read from base directory");
            return;
        }

        File output = new File(outputDirArg);
        if (!output.exists() || !output.canRead() || !output.canWrite()
                || !output.isDirectory()) {
            logger.error("Unable to write to output director");
            return;
        }

        if (base.list() == null || base.list().length == 0) {
            logger.error("The base directory is empty");
            return;
        }

        if (output.list() != null && output.list().length != 0) {
            logger.error("The output directory is not empty");
            return;
        }

        processDirectory(base, output);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        logger.error("Unable to parse arguments: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Unexpected error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }

}

public static void processDirectory(File directory, File outputDirectory)
        throws Exception {
    logger.info("Processing directory [" + directory.getAbsolutePath()
            + "]");

    for (File file : directory.listFiles()) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            File targetDir = new File(outputDirectory.getAbsolutePath()
                    + File.separator + file.getName());
            logger.info("Creating directory: "
                    + targetDir.getAbsolutePath());
            targetDir.mkdir();
            processDirectory(file, targetDir);
        } else {
            File targetFile = new File(outputDirectory.getAbsolutePath()
                    + File.separator + file.getName());

            if (file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".zip")
                    || file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".jar")) {
                logger.info("Processing archive file: "
                        + file.getAbsolutePath());

                ZipFile zipSrc = new ZipFile(file);
                Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> srcEntries = zipSrc.entries();

                ZipOutputStream outStream = new ZipOutputStream(
                        new FileOutputStream(targetFile));

                while (srcEntries.hasMoreElements()) {
                    ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) srcEntries.nextElement();
                    logger.info("Processing zip entry [" + entry.getName()
                            + "]");

                    ZipEntry newEntry = new ZipEntry(entry.getName());
                    try {
                        outStream.putNextEntry(newEntry);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        if (!e.getMessage().startsWith("duplicate entry: ")) {
                            logger.error("error: ", e);
                        } else {
                            logger.info(e.getMessage(), e);
                        }
                        outStream.closeEntry();
                        continue;
                    }

                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(
                            zipSrc.getInputStream(entry));

                    if (ImageType.findType(entry.getName()) != null) {
                        processImage(zipSrc.getName() + "!/" + entry.getName(), bis, outStream);
                    } else {
                        IOUtils.copy(bis, outStream);
                    }

                    outStream.closeEntry();
                    bis.close();
                }

                zipSrc.close();
                outStream.close();
            } else if (ImageType.findType(file.getName()) != null) {
                logger.info("Processing image: " + file.getAbsolutePath());

                FileInputStream inStream = null;
                FileOutputStream outStream = null;

                try {
                    inStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
                    processImage(file.getName(), inStream, outStream);
                } finally {
                    IOUtils.closeQuietly(inStream);
                    IOUtils.closeQuietly(outStream);
                }
            } else {
                logger.info("Processing : " + file.getAbsolutePath());

                FileInputStream inStream = null;
                FileOutputStream outStream = null;

                try {
                    inStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
                    IOUtils.copy(inStream, outStream);
                } finally {
                    IOUtils.closeQuietly(inStream);
                    IOUtils.closeQuietly(outStream);
                }

            }

        }

    }

}

public static void processImage(String fileName, InputStream input,
        OutputStream output) throws IOException {

    logger.info("Scaling image: " + fileName);

    boolean imageWriteStarted = false;
    try {
        BufferedImage out = ImageIO.read(input);

        int outWidth = out.getWidth() * 2;
        int outHeight = out.getHeight() * 2;

        BufferedImage rescaledOut = createResizedCopy(out, outWidth, outHeight);

        ImageIO.write(rescaledOut, ImageType.findType(fileName).name(),
                output);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (imageWriteStarted) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to scale image [" + fileName
                    + "]: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        } else {
            logger.error(
                    "Unable to scale [" + fileName + "]: " + e.getMessage(),
                    e);
            IOUtils.copy(input, output);
        }
    }
}

private static BufferedImage createResizedCopy(BufferedImage originalImage, int scaledWidth, int scaledHeight) {

    try {
        // Resample failed - maybe the image was too small, try another way (Scalr)
        BufferedImage scaledBI = Scalr.resize(originalImage, Scalr.Method.ULTRA_QUALITY, scaledWidth, scaledHeight);
        return scaledBI;
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {

        return scale(originalImage, 2.0);
    }
}
private static BufferedImage scale(BufferedImage source,double ratio) {
  int w = (int) (source.getWidth() * ratio);
  int h = (int) (source.getHeight() * ratio);
  BufferedImage bi = getCompatibleImage(w, h);
  Graphics2D g2d = bi.createGraphics();
  double xScale = (double) w / source.getWidth();
  double yScale = (double) h / source.getHeight();
  AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(xScale,yScale);
  g2d.drawRenderedImage(source, at);
  g2d.dispose();
  return bi;
}

private static BufferedImage getCompatibleImage(int w, int h) {
  GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
  GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
  GraphicsConfiguration gc = gd.getDefaultConfiguration();
  BufferedImage image = gc.createCompatibleImage(w, h);
  return image;
}
}
```